# Low Yearly Archives - EE3

Tags: php, ee3, low-yearly-archives

Im trying to use Low Yearly Archives to show a list months with a list to an individual month of articles.

I also want to show a list of years excluding the current year so the page will look something like this:

Jan Feb

2016 2015 2014

Ive had this running on EE2 but can't get it to work on EE3

Here is the code:

PHP:

```
<?php
$year = $this->EE->localize->format_date("%Y", $this->EE->localize->now);
?>
```

Tag:

```
{exp:low_yearly_archives channel="news" start_month="1" status="not closed" sort="desc" show_future_entries="no" start_year="<?=$year?>" end_year="<?=$year?>" dynamic="yes"}
{months}
{if num_entries > 0}
<a href="{site_url}news/archive/{year}/{month_num}/" title="{num_entries} entries in {month} {year}">{month}</a> | {num_entries}
{/if}
{/months}
{/exp:low_yearly_archives}

{exp:low_yearly_archives channel="news" status="not closed" sort="desc" end_year="<?=$year-1?>" dynamic="no"}
{if year == "<?=$year?>"}
{if:else} 
{if entries_in_year > 0}
<a href="{site_url}news/year/{year}/" title="{entries_in_year} entries in {year}"><strong>{year}</strong></a>
{/if}
{/if}
{/exp:low_yearly_archives}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "can't get it to work"? Do you get an error? Or is it not behaving the way it should?

Comment: Im getting no output at all. My PHP is wrong I guess.

Comment: Are you sure PHP is enabled on that template?

Comment: I have php enabled with and parsing "input". Im not sure the php is updated for EE3. Actually Im trying to use your example code and Im not getting any results from it either even though I have 3 articles in Feb.

Comment: Maybe EE doesn't like php in conditionals.

Comment: Ive used this code successfully with EE2 but it does´t work at all in EE3. Is this the right code for EE3: <?php
$year = $this->EE->localize->format_date("%Y", $this->EE->localize->now);
?>

Comment: Your example code is not working for me either. It lists months it doesn't render {num_entries}

Comment: Hi Low, I tried your simple example code from your website and this doesn't work in EE3 (php version 5.6). It doesn't recognise that there are any entries connected with the months. It works fine in EE2 (php version 5.5).

Comment: Just tested the example code again, and it works just fine for me in EE3.5, PHP5.6. This conditional also works: `{if year == '{current_time format="%Y"}'}THIS YEAR{/if}`

Comment: Hi Low, Thanks so much for your attention :) I figured out the problem. It seems that Yearly Archives was not recognising existing entries. When I updated them they are recognised. One strange behaviour now is that they are not being displayed correctly. If for example I have an entry with the date 6th Feb 2017 it is being listed in June meaning that it is interpreting that the date (6th) is in fact the month (June). Do you have any idea why this is?